# MVC - Sending MS CRM Entity to Strongly Typed View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 5.0 application. My controller includes an action which queries a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 application.

The action has been designed to retrieve a single row of the contact entity. However when the results arrive and the strongly typed view is rendered in the browser, I don't see the value of the field--only the property name.

Using the debugger, I have confirmed that the controller action successfully retrieves a row of data from Microsoft CRM and populates the contact class and sends it to my View.

*For example, the immediate window displays an actual value when I enter: `?contact.firstname` this yields the value: "John"*

The above example was tested at the moment when my controller returned the query results into the contact class (See below).

`var contact = (MVCNursePortal.Contact)context.ContactSet.Where(c => c.ContactId == cid).FirstOrDefault();`

But after sending the class (`return View(contact);`), no data actually arrives into my view even though the model is the right type (`@model Contact`).

For some reason, I don't seem to be passing the actual data, or my view model is incorrect.

There is only one Contact model in my namespace. Not sure where exactly where things wemt wrong--in the controller or the view?

After running the project in Internet explorer, the view simply displays the following:

---

**EditContact**

**FirstName**

---

You comments are greatly appreciated.

Code examples follow:

**Controller:**

```
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Discovery;
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata;
    using MVCNursePortal.Infrastructure;

    namespace MVCNursePortal.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            private IOrganizationService oMSCRMService;

            public ActionResult EditContact(string contactID)
            {
                CRMFunctions fns = new CRMFunctions();
                oMSCRMService = fns.fn_MSCRMConnect();
                Guid cid = new Guid(contactID);

                var context = new MVCNursePortal.xrm(oMSCRMService);

                var contact = (MVCNursePortal.Contact)context.ContactSet.Where(c => c.ContactId == cid).FirstOrDefault();

                return View(contact);
            }
        }
    }
```

**The View:**

```
    @model Contact
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "EditContact";
    }
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.FirstName)
```

**Connecting to Microsoft Dynamics CRM**

```
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Discovery;
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.ServiceModel.Description;

    namespace MVCNursePortal.Infrastructure
    {
        public class CRMFunctions
        {
            private OrganizationServiceProxy oMSCRMServiceProxy;

            private IOrganizationService oMSCRMService;
            public IOrganizationService fn_MSCRMConnect()
            {

                try
                {
                    Uri OrgURI = new      Uri(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["crmUrl"].ConnectionString);
                     Uri HomeURI = null;
                    ClientCredentials oCredentials = new ClientCredentials();

                    //Update these to be in the web.config:
                    oCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain =   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"].ToString();
                     oCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"].ToString();
                    oCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();

                    oMSCRMServiceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(OrgURI, HomeURI, oCredentials, null);
                    oMSCRMServiceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
                    oMSCRMService = (IOrganizationService)oMSCRMServiceProxy;

                    return oMSCRMService;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return oMSCRMService;
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

**Web.Config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
      -->
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="microsoft.xrm.client" type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Configuration.CrmSection, Microsoft.Xrm.Client"></section>
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MVCNursePortal-20140212082427.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVCNursePortal-20140212082427;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="crmUrl" connectionString="http://mycrmserver/customerOrgName/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"/>  
       </connectionStrings>
       <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
         <add key="Username" value="joe"/>
         <add key="Password" value="1234"/>
         <add key="Domain" value="domainname.com"/>
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
        </modules>
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have code explaining the MVCNursePortal.xrm(oMSCRMService) section of your app?  How did you create the Contact Entity class and where did the ContactSet function come from?  I too am trying to create a MVC 5 CRM app and would like to strongly type my data.

Answer (score 1):

Your output is correct for the Razor you've provided. `LabelFor()` prints the name of the property (used for printing labels next to input boxes, etc). To print out the value of the name, simply use `@Model.FirstName`.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I just tried your suggestion and you are correct. I need to learn a bit more about Razor! :)